# Matching / grouping several key value pairs with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

I am building an application that kind of 'matches' profiles together.
for example, here is a cut-down version of my schema::

**User**
Id
FirstName
LastName

**UserProfile**
Id
UserId
SomeOtherFields

**UserProfileFields**
Id
UserProfileId
Key
Value

UserProfile exists to hold some standard information (date of birth etc…)

UserProfileFields is basically a list of keys and their values, in order to build up a dictionary that looks a little something like this (again, simplified for the purposes of this question)

```
UserProfileID | Key       | Value       
123           | food      | Pizza
123           | food      | Indian
4453          | drink     | Coke
44850         | drink     | Orange Juice
88493         | food      | Pizza
448382        | food      | Chinese
```

So, from the above, we can see that profile 123 is matched to 88493 on food - they both have food|pizza

Is there a way to efficiently query this table to get a list of "matches"

I would envisage this to be run once a day, and the results stored in a separate table

for example:

**Matches**

```
MatchID | ProfileID
1       | 123
1       | 88493
```

I'm guessing something along the lines of a

```
SELECT * FROM UserProfileFields
GROUP BY Key
```

Type of query... but not sure how efficient this would be on say, 1 million rows?

Answer (score 2):

This should take care of it for you.

```
-- ============================================================================
-- BEGIN: SETUP TEST DATA
-- ============================================================================
CREATE TABLE UserProfileFields (
    UserProfileID   int
   ,[Key]           varchar(5)
   ,Value           varchar(12)
);


INSERT UserProfileFields (UserProfileID, [Key], Value)
SELECT A.*
  FROM (
        SELECT * FROM UserProfileFields WHERE 1=2
        UNION ALL SELECT 123,       'food',     'Pizza'
        UNION ALL SELECT 123,       'food',     'Indian'
        UNION ALL SELECT 4453,      'drink',    'Coke'
        UNION ALL SELECT 44850,     'drink',    'Orange Juice'
        UNION ALL SELECT 88493,     'food',     'Pizza'
        UNION ALL SELECT 448382,    'food',     'Chinese'
        UNION ALL SELECT 88493,     'drink',    'Coke'
        UNION ALL SELECT 88493,     'drink',    'Orange Juice'
       ) A;

--/*
-- Turn 8 records into 1,048,576
DECLARE @Count int; SELECT @Count = 0;
WHILE @Count < 17
  BEGIN
    INSERT UserProfileFields
    SELECT * FROM UserProfileFields

    SELECT @Count = (@Count + 1)
END
--*/
-- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserProfileFields WITH (NOLOCK)
-- ============================================================================
-- END: SETUP TEST DATA
-- ============================================================================




-- ============================================================================
-- BEGIN: Solution if Key, Value, and UserProfileID do NOT make up a unique key
-- ============================================================================
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DistinctValues', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DistinctValues;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Matches', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Matches;

SELECT [Key], UserProfileID, Value 
  INTO #DistinctValues
  FROM UserProfileFields WITH (NOLOCK)
 GROUP BY [Key], UserProfileID, Value;

SELECT A.[Key], A.Value, A.UserProfileID
  INTO #Matches
  FROM #DistinctValues A
  JOIN #DistinctValues B
    ON A.[Key]           = B.[Key]
   AND A.Value           = B.Value
   AND A.UserProfileID  <> B.UserProfileID;

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY A.[Key], A.Value) [MatchID]
      ,A.UserProfileID
      ,A.[Key]
      ,A.Value
  FROM #Matches A;
-- ============================================================================
-- END: Solution if Key, Value, and UserProfileID do NOT make up a unique key
-- ============================================================================




-- ============================================================================
-- BEGIN: Solution if Key, Value, and UserProfileID make up a unique key
-- ============================================================================
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Matches', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Matches;

SELECT A.[Key], A.Value, A.UserProfileID
  INTO #Matches
  FROM UserProfileFields A WITH (NOLOCK)
  JOIN UserProfileFields B WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON A.[Key]           = B.[Key]
   AND A.Value           = B.Value
   AND A.UserProfileID  <> B.UserProfileID;

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY A.[Key], A.Value) [MatchID]
      ,A.UserProfileID
      ,A.[Key]
      ,A.Value
  FROM #Matches A;
-- ============================================================================
-- END: Solution if Key, Value, and UserProfileID make up a unique key
-- ============================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Matches
AS
(
    SELECT  a.UserProfileID,
            a.[Key],
            a.Value,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY a.[Key]) MatchID
    FROM    UserProfileFields a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT  [Key], Value
                FROM    UserProfileFields 
                GROUP   BY [Key], Value
                HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT UserProfileID) > 1
            ) b ON  a.[Key] = b.[Key] AND
                    a.Value = b.Value
)
SELECT  MatchID, UserProfileID
FROM    Matches
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/247a9/6)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*updated: with two other matchingID*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9bfe/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use option with EXISTS() operator and covering index. This will help avoid excessive data sorting.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_Key_Value_UserProfileFields ON dbo.UserProfileFields([Key], Value) INCLUDE(UserProfileID)

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.[Key], t.Value) AS MatchID, t.UserProfileID
FROM dbo.UserProfileFields t
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.UserProfileFields t2
              WHERE t.[Key] = t2.[Key]
                AND t.Value = t2.Value
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  
              )
```

[image]

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45c8f/1)